# Facebook SDK share Photo Preview not working

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags

I'me having some troubles with sharing a link and getting a nice photo-preview.
So the sharing works: the Facebook-debugger shows the photo-preview, manually sharing the link gives the photo-preview, but sharing it with the Js-SDK gives a small box.

Manual sharing and Facebook-debugger:

[image: Large preview image]

Js-SDK-share:

[image: Small preview image]

The meta-tags:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="{{title}}"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="{{description}}"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="{{image}}"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="{{url}}"/>
```

Js:

```js
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: options.url,
}, onFacebookCallback);
```

The image is 1200x630 which is the recommended size: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images).

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Example of a link I'd like to share: http://www.twoo.com/landing/profile/5f7b71452e8149a9dcd1f52f1f860b99/278622550

Comment: Do you have the URL you are trying to share so we can help you out?

Comment: For example: http://www.twoo.com/landing/profile/5f7b71452e8149a9dcd1f52f1f860b99/278622550